# When refreshing view state in Router5, part of another view reappears

Tags: javascript, css, refresh, reload

I'm making a very basic client (ie, essentially a website) using Router5. I have my code set so that when the user clicks a button, the elements that I don't want are hidden (the class `hidden` is added). The elements that I want to appear have the `hidden` class removed. Works great. However, when I am in the non-`index` state and I refresh, an element from the `index` state reappears.

I looked in the console for debugging purposes. When I refresh, the `hidden` class from the index view is indeed removed, and I'm not sure why.

I'm relatively new to coding, so any help that I could get on this would be greatly appreciated.

This is my transition code. As I've said, it works when I'm going from one view to the other, but when I refresh a view that isn't `index`, one of the `index` elements reappears:

```
const transition = function() {
  return (toState, fromState, done) => {
    if (fromState) {
      $(`#${fromState.name}`).addClass('hidden');
    }

    $(`#${toState.name}`).removeClass('hidden');

    done();
  };
};
```

Other relevant code:

```
const routes = router.rootNode.children.map((route) => {
  return route.name;
});

const registerPaths = () => {
  routes.forEach((route) => {
    $(`a[href="#${route}"]`).on('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      router.navigate(route);
    });
  });
};


$(document).ready(function () {
  require('./router/index').start();
  require('./router/events').registerPaths();
});
```

I think that's everything. Please let me know if you need to see other code in order to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that even the DEFAULT view state needed to have `.hidden` class in the HTML. I'm still learning more about Router!